# Salesforce to Highrise migration

Tags: migration, data-migration

does anyone have any pointers on how to migrate just contact info (no notes).
Salesforce can export Accounts and Contacts - and Highrise has a single table for everything.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: well - I know Highrise makes a distinction Company/Person and stores it in a field called "kind". However - when I am trying to import my csv data - there is no field mapping for "kind". So, thinking this is kind of a primary data attribute - I am puzzled about it.

Comment: I think for in an import into Highrise you should probably look on Highrise forums or support pages.